# click on textview on listview on fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-fragments

click on textview on listview on fragment

TextView On category_row.xml textViewCategoryName

onclick SetText this textViewCategoryName ok!

CategoriesFragment.java

```
package com.example;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.adapter.CategoryArrayAdapter;
import com.example.model.CategoryDataModel;
import com.example.parser.JSONParser;
import com.example.utils.Keys;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CategoriesFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<CategoryDataModel> list;
    private CategoryArrayAdapter adapter;
    private TextView categoryCurrent;

    public CategoriesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, null);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        /**
         * Array List for Binding Data from JSON to this List
         */
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new CategoryArrayAdapter(getActivity(), list);

        /**
         * Getting List and Setting List Adapter
         */
        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.parentLayout), list.get(position).getCategoryName(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Check internet connection
         */
        //if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
        new GetDataCategories().execute();
        //} else {
        //Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.parentLayout), "اتصال به اینترنت برقرار نیست", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //}

    }

    /**
     * Creating Get Data Task for Getting Data From Web
     */
    class GetDataCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ContentLoadingProgressBar progressBar;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            /**
             * Progress Bar for User Interaction
             */
            progressBar = (ContentLoadingProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progress);
            progressBar.show();
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            /**
             * Getting JSON Object from Web Using okHttp
             */
            JSONObject jsonObject = JSONParser.getDataFromWeb("http://example.com/api-service/v1/platform_categories/");

            try {
                /**
                 * Check Whether Its NULL???
                 */
                if (jsonObject != null) {
                    /**
                     * Check Length...
                     */
                    if(jsonObject.length() > 0) {
                        /**
                         * Getting Array named "Categories" From MAIN Json Object
                         */
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Keys.KEY_CATEGORIES);

                        /**
                         * Check Length of Array...
                         */
                        int lenArray = array.length();
                        if(lenArray > 0) {
                            for(int jIndex = 0; jIndex < lenArray; jIndex++) {

                                /**
                                 * Creating Every time New Object
                                 * and
                                 * Adding into List
                                 */
                                CategoryDataModel model = new CategoryDataModel();

                                /**
                                 * Getting Inner Object from contacts array...
                                 * and
                                 * From that We will get Name of that Contact
                                 *
                                 */
                                JSONObject innerObject = array.getJSONObject(jIndex);

                                String category_name = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_CATEGORY_NAME);
                                String category_link = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_CATEGORY_LINK);


                                /**
                                 * Getting Object from Object "other"
                                 */
                                //JSONObject otherObject = innerObject.getJSONObject(Keys.KEY_NAME);
                                //String other = otherObject.getString(Keys.KEY_NAME_SUB);


                                model.setCategoryName(category_name);
                                model.setCategoryLink(category_link);

                                /**
                                 * Adding data in List...
                                 */
                                list.add(model);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                Log.i(JSONParser.TAG, "" + je.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            /**
             * Progress Bar for User Interaction
             */
            progressBar.hide();

            /**
             * Checking if List size if more than zero then
             * Update ListView
             */
            if(list.size() > 0) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.parentLayout), "مشکلی در اتصال به سرورهای سخنک رخ داده است!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

CategoryArrayAdapter.java

```
package com.example.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.R;
import com.example.model.CategoryDataModel;

import java.util.List;

public class CategoryArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CategoryDataModel> {

    List<CategoryDataModel> modelList;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    // Constructors
    public CategoryArrayAdapter(Context context, List<CategoryDataModel> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        modelList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public CategoryDataModel getItem(int position) {
        return modelList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_row, parent, false);
            vh = ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
            view.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        CategoryDataModel item = getItem(position);

        vh.textViewCategoryName.setText(item.getCategoryName());

        return vh.rootView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public final RelativeLayout rootView;
        public final TextView textViewCategoryName;

        private ViewHolder(RelativeLayout rootView, TextView textViewCategoryName) {
            this.rootView = rootView;
            this.textViewCategoryName = textViewCategoryName;
        }

        public static ViewHolder create(RelativeLayout rootView) {
            TextView textViewCategoryName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategoryName);
            return new ViewHolder(rootView, textViewCategoryName);
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_categories.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ListView app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

category_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewProfilePhoto">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCategoryName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            tools:text="Quote Content" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What you wanna do ?

Comment: I want to click on the category textViewCategoryName On category_row.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set an `onClickListener` to your `TextView` in your `ViewHolder`.

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    public final RelativeLayout rootView;
    public final TextView textViewCategoryName;

    private ViewHolder(RelativeLayout rootView, TextView textViewCategoryName) {
        this.rootView = rootView;
        this.textViewCategoryName = textViewCategoryName;
    }

    public static ViewHolder create(RelativeLayout rootView) {
        TextView textViewCategoryName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategoryName);
        textViewCategoryName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do whatever you want
            }
        });
        return new ViewHolder(rootView, textViewCategoryName);
    }
}
```